# if $A$ is $2 \times 2$ matrix find $\lim_{n \to \infty} A^n$

Tags: calculus, matrices, limits

if $A$ is $2 \times 2$ given by

$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
 1& \frac{\theta}{n} \\ 
-\frac{\theta}{n} & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

matrix find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} A^n$$

I tried like this:

$$A-I=\begin{bmatrix}
 0& \frac{\theta}{n} \\ 
-\frac{\theta}{n} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

So

$$(A-I)^2= -\frac{\theta^2}{n^2} I$$ Generalizing we get

$$(A-I)^n=-\frac{\theta^n}{n^n} I$$

any clue or hint here?

Comment: May be you can try to diagonalize the matrix?

Comment: Your expression for $(A-I)^n$ doesn't work, try it for $n=1$ or $n=3$.

Comment: Maybe thinking geometrically helps. What does $A$ do to the plane?

Comment: $A^m = \left( \begin{array}{cc}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

diagonalize the matrix:

$$
A= \begin{bmatrix}
 1& \frac{\theta}{n} \\ 
-\frac{\theta}{n} & 1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
 i& -i \\ 
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1-\frac{\theta i}{n}&0 \\ 
0 & 1+\frac{\theta i}{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 -\frac{i}{2}& \frac{1}{2} \\ 
\frac{i}{2} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

than use the limits:

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{\theta i}{n}\right)^n =e^{-\theta i} \qquad\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{\theta i}{n}\right)^n =e^{\theta i}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let p(t) be a polynomial function with variable t.

Let $ p(t)=\det(tI-A) $.

$$p(t)=t^2 -2t+1+ \frac{θ^2 }{n^2}$$

By Cayley-Hamilton theorem, p(matrix A)= zero matrix

Set p(t)=0, t= 1 (+ or -) θi/n, and these are the eigenvalues.